# Having Trouble importing skinned mesh into PaperVision3d 3.0 from COLLADA

Tags: skinning, papervision3d, collada

I can export just a mesh, but a mesh with a Skin modifier bound to Biped does not work. The skin is not imported as TriangleMesh3D or a skinning class, and is instead a DisplayObject3D class that lacks geometry. No warnings are given.

Any idea how I should import a COLLADA file with skinning importation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to load it as a DAE as opposed to a COLLADA. For instance:

```
var cow2:DAE = new DAE();
cow2.load(new XML(new CowDAE()), cowMaterials);
```